# USB Connection?

Tags: usb

I've seen this type of USB drive several times, but I've never actually owned one until today. I have a MacBook Pro, and so I have no idea how to connect this kind of flash drive to it. Does it still go through the USB port somehow, or do I need an adapter of some sort? Thanks!

[image: weird USB drive]
<sub>(source: [qualitylogoproducts.com](http://www.qualitylogoproducts.com/computer-accessories/key-flash-drive-2-gb-extralarge.jpg))</sub>

Comment: @Glorfindel - please don't make pointless edits to absurdly off-topic questions which have been properly closed for the past five years!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ChrisStratton it's a script which doesn't know the definition of "properly closed". Since it only edits two posts every three days, the 'damage' is minimal, and it's a *suggested* edit, so apparently two other users found it OK.

Comment: If you're going to run a script here, you need to take responsibility for the result, and fix it not to edit posts that are irreparable.  Offloading the review of what your code is doing to other people is seriously improper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You plug it into the USB port. It does still fit the USB port even though it's missing half the structural elements of a USB plug.

Comment: The drawback of this connector is that it can be inserted into the port the wrong side. It doesn't damage the port or the device, but it makes no connection without any notification. I have mistaken with such connection several times myself.